# prueba tecnica con spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

disculpen por molestarlos con este tipo de preguntas pero como soy nuevo dentro de la programacion y ademas con spring-boot  voy a pasar una prueba tecnica con este framework
me dieron este ejercicio que debo hacerlo lo mas pronto posible.

Solo para confirmar con la comunidad.
yo debo hace el **back** y hacer los mismos endpoint que esta en la documentacion.
y hacer las pruebas  en postman para ver si mis urls funcionan correctamente

```
swagger: '2.0' 
info: 
  version: v2 
  title: User and Password 
basePath: "/" 

tags: 
  - name: Compliance
    description: tools to verify the compliance rules
  - name: CRUD
    description: Create Update Verify for user object

paths: 
  "/api/compliance/password/{password}": 
    get: 
      tags: 
      - Compliance
      summary: Return true if password is compliant or false and reasons if not, 
          Complexity =
          at least 8 characters
          at least one digit
          at least one special character (!,#,$,%,&,@)
          at least one uppercase letter 
      consumes:
      - application/json 
      produces: 
      - application/json 
      parameters: 
      - name: password 
        in: path 
        description: password for analysis
        required: true 
        type: string 
      responses: 
        '200': 
          description: compliance result
          schema: 
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Compliance"
```

otra parte del codigo

```
 "/api/user/": 
    post: 
      tags: 
      - CRUD
      summary: Create a new user
      consumes: 
      - application/json
      produces: 
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: User
        in: body
        description: login to retrieve
        required: true 
        schema: 
              $ref: '#/definitions/User'
      responses: 
        '201': 
          description: user created
        '409':
          description: user already exists
        '400': 
          description: password is not Compliant 
          schema: 
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Compliance" 
            
  "/api/user/{login}": 
    get: 
      tags: 
      - CRUD
      summary: ...
      produces: 
      - application/json 
      parameters: 
      - name: login
        in: path 
        description: login to retrieve
        required: true 
        type: string 
      responses: 
        '200': 
          description: user found
          schema: 
            "$ref": "#/definitions/User" 
        '404': 
          description: user not found
```

```
 "/api/user/{login}/verify": 
    post: 
      tags: 
      - CRUD
      summary: ...
      consumes: 
      - application/json 
      produces: 
      - application/json 
      parameters: 
      - name: login
        in: path 
        description: login to retrieve
        required: true 
        type: string 
      - name: password
        in: body 
        description: password
        required: true 
        schema: 
              $ref: '#/definitions/Password'
      responses: 
        '200': 
          description: password is ok
        '403': 
          description: invalid password

definitions: 
  Compliance: 
    type: object 
    properties: 
      isValid: 
        type: boolean 
      reason: 
        type: string 
  
  User: 
    type: object
    properties: 
      name: 
        type:  string
      phone:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
        
  Password: 
    type: string
```

**Gracias** por su ayuda

Comment: Y qué es lo que necesitas exactamente? Lo tienes hecho y quieres que te ayudemos a testearlo?

Comment: @Jakala me lo acabaron de dar el ejercicio y necesito saber si lo comprendi bien. para ponerme en la tarea de hacerlo

Comment: Cuál es el error con el código?

Comment: @Bicho no hay error solo que me dieron este ejercicio a hacer si quiero saber si lo entendi bien

Comment: Si lo que quieres saber es si has entendido bien el ejercicio, no podemos ayudarte sin saber el enunciado completo. De todas formas, si tienes que hacer un backend, la documentación que te están dando (swagger) es suficiente para saber que debes hacer, pues te dicen los endpoints, los verbos, las respuedtas esperadas...

Comment: @Jakala Es que no hay enunciado, me dijero solo el ejercicio y me dijero que la documentacion  swagger es clara. Esta claro que debo hacer un backend y tener un controller  donde esten los endpoints que aparecen en la documentacion swagger es correcto?

Comment: Te recomiendo que desarrolles el ejercicio y cuando tengas algún error con una parte del código, lo preguntes acá. Como te dijeron, es complicado ayudarte sin saber lo que toca hacer.

Comment: Si has entendido bien, lo que debes crear son RestController modelándolos según la documentation que presentas, que es todo lo que necesitas. Ahora bien esta web es para preguntas técnicas sobre programación así que lo mas seguro es que la pregunta sea cerrada.

Comment: @Jakala comence hacer el el ejercicio  les dejo mi repo https://github.com/gache/testuser.git  para ver tener una opinion externa ** /api/compliance/password/{password} ** tengo problemas con este me podrias decir donde estar el problema  les agradezco por su ayuda sus comentarios son bienevenido